# WPF Paper-like control

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a WPF control that look like a white sheet of paper floating inside a container of some sort. I want to be able to drag the paper around and zoom.

I am rather new to WPF and I would like to know which control I should look into to create that.

I presume the paper itself will be a inkcanvas, but what control should the container be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look at the **ScrollViewer** WPF control. Here's an [overview at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750665.aspx). This should provide a scrollable view of a larger contained control like a Canvas for example.

Here's [another link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37349/Creating-A-Scrollable-Control-Surface-In-WPF.aspx?display=Print) which seems to address your need.

Answer (score 0):

WPF already has FixedPage document pages that look like normal paper and when you put it inside document viewer, it looks exactly same as Adobe Reader, and you can put all you want inside FixedPage, you can also derive from FixedPage and put your stuff in it.

Comment: I want to be able to place other control inside it. Like a grid and other basic control. Will they still be editable inside the DocumentViewer?

Comment: You can put most of editable controls in fixed page but i am not aware of datagrid.